# AJAX POST Failed "Connection Close"

Tags: php, ajax, post

I am using AJAX POST method to call a PHP script. The call is working great and successful most of the time and everything is fine. Sometimes (1/100 percentage of occurrence), I get the response:

```
<HTML></HTML>
```

And in the response header I get:
**Connection:** Close

The **status code** is **200**

The AJAX Javacript code for the POST method:

```
xmlHttp.open("POST", site_url+ "/ajax.php", true);
xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xmlHttp.send("&par1=a&par2=b");
```

**Note:** When I was using the GET, I never got such errors. GET Code:

```
xmlHttp.open("GET", site_url + "/ajax.php?par1=a&par2=b", true);
xmlHttp.send(null);
```

**UPDATE:**

The error I get on the browser: 
**SyntaxError: Unexpected token <**

The code of the handler function:

```
xmlHttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
    if(xmlHttp.readyState==4){
        if(xmlHttp.status==200){
            var resp = xmlHttp.responseText.trim();
            if(resp!=''){ 
                eval(resp);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The PHP script as below (ajax.php):

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['par1'])){
    $par1= mysql_escape_string($_POST['par1']);
}

if(isset($_POST['par2'])){
    $par2= mysql_escape_string($_POST['par2']);
}
?>

alert('Request Succeeded: '+ '<?php echo $par1 ?>' + '<?php echo $par2 ?>');
```

Would greatly appreciate if you have any clarification on how to fix this issue.

Thank you!

Comment: `xmlHttp.send("&par1=a&par2=b");` to `xmlHttp.send("par1=a&par2=b");` , does this work?

Comment: I'm quite sure the problem isn't the request, as you receive a response, but the way you process it server-side or the format of the response.

Comment: SunnyRGupta: I did as you said but that didn't make sense.
@Bartdude: Please see my update on the question, I have included the JS handler function and the ajax.php code. Please advise. Thanks a lot.

Comment: it all looks fine to me, I don't understand your problem. If everything is fine 99% of the time, then your code is most probably OK (although this `alert` response is quite ugly code if you ask me), and the problem could be the data you're sending/treating.

Comment: @Bartdude: Thanks. My problem is that when I use the POST, I get 1% this error (connection closed). But When I use the GET, 100% working fine! Maybe the server slowness sometimes causes this error?